# Connect to Bluetooth with Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am working on an Android App whose purpose is to connect to a Bluetooth device which is waiting for input and is already paired with my mobile phone.

I already have the MAC adres of the device into a string and I managed to send the Mac Adress to a new activity where I'll do the connection. The problem is I don't understand how to...

I have been trying to use http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html and it has worked so far but when it comes to the connection part I just can't understand it anymore.

It talks about an UUID but it doesn't tell me where to find it, after some research and testing I see it can't be a string and in an example i found on the net, somebody was parsing a String or INt into UUID and the numbers looked nothing like a MAC adress...

This is what I have so far and where i think the connection should be done

```
try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
```

I can't find that UUID nor understand how to cast my Mac Adress to it.

And if it's all wrong, does anybody have a CLEAR and COMPLETE code example which explains HOW to connect to the device and what I should do with the MAC adress? I can't seem to find anything clear and working on the net...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question, but I designed a controller for an electronic LED display, and then wrote an android app based off the bluetooth chat example in the SDK in order to send messages to the sign with my phone

Check here:[BluetoothSignController](https://github.com/evanrich/Bluetooth-LED-Sign) for the project, and you can see some screenshots and code examples on how the android portion works [here](https://github.com/evanrich/Bluetooth-LED-Sign/wiki/Android-and-PC-Remotes%3a--how-do-they-work?)

Hopefully that can tell you how to connect your phone to whatever you're connecting to.  You don't need the MAC address, just scan and pair.

Comment: I'm actually using an Arduino board, my aim is to send 1 and 2 to it by bluetooth to turn a led on and off ;). I'll check this out thanks!

Comment: in that case, take a look at the arduino code as well.   Ignore the board schematics, as that revision failed serial communications checks (issue with board design).  The code posted worked on my arduino uno dev board.  I'm in the process of redoing everything on that page from scratch in a new repo, but a combination of the android and arduino code along with the wiki pages should tell you what you need to know.

Comment: I actually already have the programming on the Arduino side since I've been listening (showing on LCD screen) on data sent by my laptop using putty ^^. I think with your code and janos's I'll manage to get a hold on this! I'll come back soon ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can find a full working example in the open-source BluetoothViewer app:
https://github.com/janosgyerik/bluetoothviewer

Specifically the code to connect to Bluetooth devices is here:
https://github.com/janosgyerik/bluetoothviewer/blob/master/src/net/bluetoothviewer/BluetoothChatService.java

The UUID is something you generate yourself, and just save it as a constant in your app. I'm not quite sure what's the point of that, but that's just how it works. You can generate a UUID using the `uuidgen` command line tool, simply run without parameters. In Mac OS X `uuidgen` should be installed by default, in Debian (and probably Ubuntu) it's in the `uuid-runtime` package.

I created this Android app precisely for this kind of purpose: debug connections with any Bluetooth device you want to connect to, observe and understand its protocol. I hope you'll find this helpful.

Comment: // Unique UUID for this application
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");

Oh so this means the UUID is actually for the app that is runing and the String you input is just random and should just be different for apps runing at the same time in the same network, interesting...

Comment: This code seems very well commented! I'll look through it tomorrow see if I can get things to work! thanks!

Comment: @magnus yup, like that. Use the `uuidgen` tool to generate your own UUID. This tool is installed by default on Mac OS X, in Debian (and probably Ubuntu) it's in the `uuid-runtime` package.

Comment: Will prolly get on this next week. Project has been on hold since I was passing my exams. :)

Comment: Has been years! I managed to get it working and control my leds with my laptop, I ended up using the first answer to get it working I believe (since I added it as accepted answer, have to admit it's been a while :))